# React / Material-UI onClick event trigger more than once when use in data.map() Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, material-ui

First, my English is not so good.

```
{data.sort(getSorting(order, orderBy))
   .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
   .map(n => {
       {/*........*/}
       <Button onClick={this.handleLsClick}>
          Open Menu
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          onClose={this.handleLsClose}
          aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
          open={open}
        >
          <div>
            <List>
              {[1,2,3,4,5].map(e => (
                <ListItem button key={e}>
                  <ListItemText primary={e} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
        {/*........*/}
```

Basically this codes works fine, But if I put them into the Loop (Like fetch data from Database), When I click the Button to show data, onClick events fired more than once, Actually fired until == "data.length" !

You can see Full sample on CodeSandbox for better Information.

[image: Edit Material demo]

At code sandbox Click the "OPEN MENU", and you will see that What's happened.
For more clarity,open demo.js and find "data" array at Line 199, Set just 1 entry and you will see that onClick event run just once, But if you Add more entry the onClick event Fired more and more...

Any ideas Guys?
Thanks Btw.

Comment: I went to the CodeSandbox example, added `console.log('foo');` inside `handleLsClick()`, checked 4 or 5 of the checkboxes, then clicked `OPEN MENU`.  `handleLsClick()` only fired 1 time.

Comment: @AdamDavis yeah you're right, I think real problem is Dialog appearing more than once, How can i fix that?
And no difference if I use Menu or Dialog, It's appear more than 1 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a workaround to solve this problem (Because I don't know if this is a bug or not, I called that workaround).

First, **move Dialog out of the loop**. I did it with custom Component.

```
class MyDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          onClose={this.props.onClose}
          aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
          open={this.props.openState}
        >
          <div>
            <List>
              {this.props.myList.map(e => (
                <ListItem button key={e.id}>
                  <ListItemText primary={e.name} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Then call it like that in Loop:

```
<Button onClick={this.handleLsClick} data-ids={n.id}>Open Menu</Button>
```

I can post complete code, But In our Language there is a proverb that says: "Bring some pressure to your brain".
However, the code is complete right now.

I used the dataset to be able to identify and separate information from each other.

For me, this code is not all I want, more work to do for separating data. But I think it answers this question.